# Missing libv4l for OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-16.04, v4l

I am trying to use my webcam with OpenCV to run my application.
However, when I tried to get the frame with videoCapture, and it gives me this error.

> VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by
>   OpenCV Sample: ../test/test.cpp:3331

[image: OpenCV build configuration]

After checking the issue, some suggestions saying that to use this command to run the app

```
LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l2convert.so" ./MY-APP
```

But I don't have this library file in the system /usr/lib/libv4l/v4l2convert.so

I am not sure where I could get this library, or does it come with OpenCV itself?

Thanks

Edit: Also tried

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-0
[sudo] password for nvidia: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libv4l-0 is already the newest version (1.10.0-1).
libv4l-0 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this lib [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=quantal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=v4l2convert.so)

It is a link to *ubuntu packages*, the package that should have the lib is `libv4l-0`, as you can see in the link.

Comment: Thanks, get it works now. my libv4l library is in different path because I am using nvidia TX2. After read the link, I found my correct path is /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so

Comment: I'm glad I could help!